# Is there a way to pass a struct or any other custom datatype in an exec function

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to make a program that can pass a custom datatype like struct for example to another code using exec function.
So I was wondering if there is any possible way for me to do it.
IK that exec has its own syntax to accept file name and a list of string (char*) parameters but I want to do some illegal coding.

Sample Code:

```
struct Student {

    int    std_roll_len;
    char * student_roll;
    int    std_name_len;
    char * student_name;
    float  student_cgpa;
    void (*std_data_input)  (struct Student*);
    void (*std_data_display)(struct Student*);
    void (*std_data_destroy)(struct Student*);
};

extern void std_data_input  (struct Student*);
extern void std_data_display(struct Student*);
extern void std_data_destroy(struct Student*);

int main() {

    char filename[] = "./Task_1_Receiver";

    char std_cgpa[16];
    struct Student student = {0, NULL,
                  0, NULL, 0.0,
                   std_data_input, 
                   std_data_display, 
                   std_data_destroy};
    student.std_data_input(&student);
    sprintf(std_cgpa, "%g", student.student_cgpa);

    //char std_id  [] = "F2019266178";
    //char std_name[] = "Mehroz Mustafa";
    //char std_cgpa[] = "1.0";
    //-> char* argv[] = {std_id, std_name, std_cgpa};

    printf("Opening Student_Receiver!\n");
    execl(filename, 
        student.student_roll,
        student.student_name, 
        std_cgpa, NULL);
    printf("Closing Student_Receiver.exe!\n");
    // any on of exec func (filename, struct Student, NULL); THIS ILLEGAL STATEMENT TO BREAK THE LAWS OF CODING 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only cross-platform solution is to serialize your data and pass it in through `stdin` to the child process. Alternatively you could use shared-memory for IPC however that is platform-specific and breaks _easily_ (as all programs must have identical structure definitions, including things like member padding, alignment, etc) so I don't recommend it.

Comment: "but I want to do some illegal coding." - Unlike national laws, which _can_ be broken, you cannot violate the laws imposed by your compiler, and if the compiler won't build your program then you cannot possibly run it.

Comment: There is no force on earth which can hold me from breaking the laws of programming

Comment: Yes there is: a compiler error.